# AllJoyn Android - LightingDirector crash when I run the demo twice (and the back key is pressed)

Tags: java, android, alljoyn, lifx

I am creating an Android app that uses AllJoyn to connect to a Lifx bulb and provides functionality to control this bulb. I used the tutorial app and the sample app from AllJoyn demonstrating their lightning sdk as a basis.

When the app is loaded it provides the user with a list of the current bulbs on the network. When the app is sent to the background (with the back key and not the home key) and then resumed, the LightingDirector returns an empty array as if there is no lights and I don't know why. I've noticed their Android lighting tutorial app also doesn't display my bulbs when resumed from the background either, so I suspect an SDK bug.

To fix this I am current using System.exit(0) in my onDestroy() method to solve the issue, but this is not a good solution. Does anyone know of a way to solve this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NextControllerConnectionListener {

    private static final int CONTROLLER_CONNECTION_DELAY = 5000;
    public LightingDirector lightingDirector;
    private ListView lv;
    private ItemListView lampAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Lamp> lamps = new ArrayList<Lamp>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.initViews();

        // STEP 1: Initialize a lighting controller with default configuration.
        LightingController lightingController = LightingController.get();
        lightingController.init(new LightingControllerConfigurationBase(getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath("").getAbsolutePath()));
        lightingController.start();

        // STEP 2: Instantiate the director, add the custom listener, then start.
        lightingDirector = LightingDirector.get();
        lightingDirector.setNetworkConnectionStatus(true);
        lightingDirector.postOnNextControllerConnection(this, CONTROLLER_CONNECTION_DELAY);
        lightingDirector.start("TutorialApp");

    }

    private void initViews() {
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lampAdapter = new ItemListView(this, this.lamps);
        lv.setAdapter(lampAdapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                goToPage2(position);
                //send which one I have clicked on
            }
        });
    }

    private void goToPage2(int position) {
        Intent dbIntent2 = new Intent(this, BulbSettingActivity.class);
        dbIntent2.putExtra("position", position);
        startActivity(dbIntent2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onControllerConnected() {
        Lamp[] lightingDirectorLamps = lightingDirector.getLamps();

        if (lightingDirectorLamps.length > 0) {
            // clear out whatever is in there
            this.lamps.clear();

            // add the lamps back
            for (Lamp lamp : lightingDirectorLamps) {
                this.lamps.add(lamp);
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    lampAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        lightingDirector.stop();
        System.exit(0);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

On the LFS Tutorial App, I get  that exception:

02-19 10:02:44.746 16855-16885/org.allseen.lsf.tutorial I/System.out: AllJoynManager.stop(): succeeded

02-19 10:02:44.771 16855-16885/org.allseen.lsf.tutorial I/System.out: AllJoynManager.destroy()

02-19 10:02:50.496 16855-16855/org.allseen.lsf.tutorial E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: org.allseen.lsf.tutorial, PID: 16855

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.allseen.lsf.tutorial/org.allseen.lsf.tutorial.TutorialActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.Thread.interrupt()' on a null object reference

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3231)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3327)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1771)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7144)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:731)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.Thread.interrupt()' on a null object reference

at org.allseen.lsf.sdk.manager.DefaultLightingSystemQueue.stop(DefaultLightingSystemQueue.java:116)

at org.allseen.lsf.sdk.manager.LightingSystemManager.setQueue(LightingSystemManager.java:231)

at org.allseen.lsf.sdk.manager.LightingSystemManager.init(LightingSystemManager.java:156)

at org.allseen.lsf.sdk.LightingDirector.start(LightingDirector.java:444)

at org.allseen.lsf.sdk.LightingDirector.start(LightingDirector.java:400)

at org.allseen.lsf.tutorial.TutorialActivity.onCreate(TutorialActivity.java:58)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6840)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3184)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3327)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1771)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7144)

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to get the LSF working. Finally I was able to get it running. Here is the code I was able to get working https://github.com/JunaidBabu/AllJoyn_LSF-sample

But, it's huge and a mess. Your code looks much simpler. If you don't mind could you please share your code?

Thanks :)